# Estimate the shape of an object based on flux curve

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, data-analysis, photometry, apparent-magnitude

Is there an aproximation to know the shape of a dust cloud,etc based on the magnitude/flux curves of stars they transit? Example, can I know if the shape is (at least in 2 dimensions) elliptical, round or just irregular? [image: If somehow the difference in magnitude does not come from the star itself, how can I know the shape of perhaps something that is passing by?]

Source of image: https://science.thewire.in/the-sciences/betelgeuse-dimming-stellar-lifecycle-hypotheses/  (it's from AAVSO)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you add a link to the source of the image? I know your question is general and this is just an example, but it's always important to cite and credit sources of images included in posts. *Thanks!*